# Return a JWT after authenticating via Open Id

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core Web API where the user logins via Steam.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = SteamAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddSteam(options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnAuthenticated = ctx => // Create user
        });

    // ...
}
```

For now I'm using a cookie and both the authentication and authorization are working fine. But I'd like to use JWTs. If I simply replace `AddCookie` by `AddJwtBearer` I get the following exception: `The authentication handler registered for scheme 'Bearer' is 'JwtBearerHandler' which cannot be used for SignInAsync`.

In this [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenId.Providers/issues/50), it says that I would need a OpenID Connect server but I don't understand why because if I wanted to write the JWT logic by myself, I could generate the token in the open id callback and return it to the user. Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

**See @KévinChalet's comment about the security issue with the below code.**

Call HandleResponse in `SteamAuthenticationOptions.Events.OnTicketReceived` so it doesn't call `SignInAsync` and to be able to do the redirect yourself to join the jwt.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options => // ...)
        .AddSteam(options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnAuthenticated = ctx =>
            {
                var res = ctx.User[SteamAuthenticationConstants.Parameters.Response];
                var players = res[SteamAuthenticationConstants.Parameters.Players];
                var player = players.First.ToObject<SteamPlayer>();
                // Create user and generate jwt, then
                ctx.Request.HttpContext.Items["jwt"] = jwt;
            });

            options.Events.OnTicketReceived = ctx =>
            {
                ctx.HandleResponse();

                var jwt = ctx.Request.HttpContext.Items["jwt"] as string;
                ctx.Response.Redirect(QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(ctx.ReturnUri, "token", jwt));
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });

    // ...
}
```

When the authentication succeeds after challenging Steam, a jwt is generated and the user is redirected to `{ReturnUri}?token={jwt}`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach for the reason mentioned [here](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenId.Providers/issues/50#issuecomment-586726240).